# Is there a way to use iPhone as a numpad for iPad apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

From what I can tell iPad iOS wont allow keyboard input from an iPhone, but just wanted to check here and make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: How would you expect this to work, if it were possible?

Comment: I'm thinking if iPhone could just act as a Bluetooth keyboard that's one way, but I imagine that's not allowed for some reason. The only other way would maybe to use a web server that could get the keystroke, and IDK if iPad iOS will allow it, but somehow get that input from the web server, but imagine might have to have yet another app open? I'm not sure though... which is why I'm here :D

Comment: Actually it's viable. It's like using bluetooth or network to send keystroke from iPhone to iPad. It doesn't need a server. Simply making two devices connect via bluetooth or network will be fine. But it indeed needs app to be run on each device.